# How can you exit a switch_user by Symfony 3.4?

Tags: impersonation, symfony-3.4

I have a project with the possability to switch from user. The impersonator works, but I can't leave the impersonator. So I stay login with the user where I to switch.

For example: User A is login and switch to user B. When They click on /?_switch_user=_exit, then you expect that user is go back to user A. But the user stay by user B.

What can be the problem?

This information have I included in the security.yml:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            two_factor:
                auth_form_path: 2fa_login
                check_path: 2fa_login_check
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                default_target_path: homepage
                always_use_default_target_path: false #true
                #csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:
                path:   fos_user_security_logout
                target: /
            anonymous:    true
            logout_on_user_change: false
            switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Update: The user A is a ROLE_ADMIN and B is ROLE_CONSUMER

Routing:

```
home_redirect:
    path:     /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index, _locale: 'nl' }
    requirements:
        _locale:  nl|en|fr
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    defaults: {_locale: 'nl'}
    type: annotation
    requirements:
        _locale:  nl|en|fr
```

Update 2:
The error what is comming by redirect to exit:
[error of wrong user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NEJR.png)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're linking to root using `/?_switch_user=_exit`, ensure that your firewall definition covers that path:

```
        main:
            pattern: ^/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. But this is all ready added to the firewall.
See on my request the more info

Comment: @PatrickVollenbroek What does your debug profiler say when you try the exit link?

Comment: I have give the response in the message above. You can see that there is an error. But I don't know how this is happend. The Url is /nl/admin, in the firewall stays that /.../admin is only for Admin

Comment: Have you any ideas?

Comment: @PatrickVollenbroek Seems like a potential problem in how you have configured FOSUserBundle. Can you share your configuration for it (fos_user.yaml?) What is your configuration for "fos_user.user_class"?